# google maps api V3でマーカー上のインフォウィンドにボタンを作る方法を教えてください

Tags: javascript, html5, api, google-maps

google map apiでwebアプリケーションを作成しています。プレイスライブラリで一定範囲内を検索し、検索にヒットしたものでルート検索で自分だけの道順を作れるアプリを開発しようと思っています。

そこでマーカー上に表示されるインフォウィンドにボタンを追加して、中継地点として登録したいと思っているのですがインフォウィンドにボタンを追加する方法が見つかりません。

初歩的なものでいいので教えてください。

Answer (score 2):

InfoWindowクラスのコンストラクタで設定するのはどうでしょうか。

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: '<input type="button" value="click!"/>'
});
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。ボタンを追加することができました。ここからがんばってみます。